# HTML Canvas putImageData with transparency causes incorrect RGB to be saved

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, png

I am trying to set individual pixels in the HTML canvas by using putImageData().  When I do this and then immediately read those pixels back out using getImageData(), the RBG values I just set have been changed! See example:

```
var ct = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = ct.getImageData(0,0,1,1);
var data = image.data;

data[0] = 200; //r
data[1] = 100; //g
data[2] = 50; //b
data[3] = 25; //a

console.log(data); //[200, 100, 50, 25]  Yeah :)

ct.putImageData(image,0,0);
var debug = ct.getImageData(0,0,1,1);

console.log(debug.data); //[204, 102, 51, 25] Boo :(
```

If I set the alpha channel to 255 (no transparency) then the RGB values aren't altered.  If I set the alpha channel to 0 (transparent) then the RGB comes back as 0,0,0. Obviously it has something to do with transparency. It probably has something to do with the RGB color space and math.

I am trying to figure out why this happens or at least be able to predict the results in some way. Can someone please clue me in about what is going on here?

Comment: When alpha is zero the RGB will be zeroed when you put it back on the canvas. There is nothing that can be done to prevent this.

Comment: @Blindman67,you can set the alpha 1 instead. But it will still lost the original RGB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to the process of compositing and in particular with premultiplying the alpha channel. The [standard states](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-putimagedata):

> Due to the lossy nature of converting to and from premultiplied alpha
>   colour values, pixels that have just been set using putImageData()
>   might be returned to an equivalent getImageData() as different values.

It's a relative deep and wide topic, but if you want to dive into the particulars for the math behind it, I would recommend looking at the Porter-Duff algorithms found at [this](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#porterduffcompositingoperators) link. See in particular blending and alpha compositing. Considering also that the browser uses 8-bit integer values in these formulas.

Comment: +1 The festering sore that is W3C why are they standardising contemporary software based on a 30 year old and flawed paper. RGB values are logarithmic and the Porter-Duff algorithms are linear. I guess nothing will change if nobody complains...

Comment: @Blindman67 ok, I suddenly felt old cause I can remember when this started to leak into smaller computers (genlocks, 32-bit cards etc.). :) But in fairness, they do convert to and from linear via gamma or ICC. XYZ color space could be considered but it's a bit more computational heavy. I have a feeling we'll be stuck for many years (thanks for the vote btw.).

Comment: same here, time flies 1984 I was still awe struck at the raw power of my 8Bit 6502, and glorious 640pixel 1Bit hi-res . Genlocks!! that was stuff for mega bucks and TV stations...

Comment: 1984 here too, as well as 6502, but mine was trapped inside a VIC20 with glorious 4k and 22 chars width. My negotiation attempts for a 16k cartridge failed miserably but I ended up with an esoteric Spectravideo 328mkII later on. The genlock stuff came some years later with the Amiga. Some of my first freelance assignments was with tv stations. They had toys like SGI Onyx2 and Quantel Paintbox - and one Amiga with a genlock. The VideoToaster wasn't available for PAL IIRC so this was kind of the substitute. But I loved the Amiga, many fun memories.

Comment: LOL I moved to the Atari800XL the following year, slower clock but much better graphics, then to the Amiga. Found a job writing games for the Amiga, by far the best machine at the time, then onto arcade design and IMOS T800's 16 CPUs 20-25Mhz each (literally burn you to touch) 3 - 34010 graphics chips for a whopping 360MIPS and 38mb RAM packed into three 12Mhz 286 chassis's that where nothing but IO and power. My brief, "Show us what it can do!" Programmers heaven. Yes fun memories. Nice to hear from a fellow 8bitter..... :)